# How to remove duplicates with different counts

Tags: sql

*How to remove duplicates if there is in two tables same department names but different counts. If there is same departments, program shouldn't take department with 0*

```
select  distinct d.fullname,count(h.isn)
from subdept d

left join subhuman h on h.deptisn=d.isn
left join subject j on h.isn=j.isn
left join emilitary em on em.emplisn=j.isn
where   h.sex = 'М' and em.milsign='Y'
group by rollup (d.fullname)

union

select d.fullname, 0 from subdept d
```

current result is in:

[image: in this screenshot]

expected result is:

[image: expected result]

Comment: "subhuman" lol!

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: thanks for comments Majesties! 
I'll take into account

Comment: Provide sample data from each table ("scrub" any  private data). This allows for testing of suggestions and usually result in faster resolution.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
select d.fullname, ISNULL(dd.c,0)  from subdept d
LEFT JOIN 
(
    select  distinct d.fullname,count(h.isn) c
    from subdept d

    left join subhuman h on h.deptisn=d.isn
    left join subject j on h.isn=j.isn
    left join emilitary em on em.emplisn=j.isn
    where   h.sex = 'М' and em.milsign='Y'
    group by rollup (d.fullname)
) dd
ON d.fullname=dd.fullname
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select d.fullname,count(distinct h.isn)
from subdept d

left join subhuman h on h.deptisn=d.isn
left join subject j on h.isn=j.isn
left join emilitary em on em.emplisn=j.isn
where   h.sex = 'М' and em.milsign='Y'
group by rollup (d.fullname)

union

select d.fullname, 0 from subdept d
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you just want to move the condition on `em.milsign` to the `on` clause.  This condition is turning the outer join to an inner join:

```
select d.fullname, count(h.isn)
from subdept d left join
     subhuman h
     on h.deptisn = d.isn left join
     subject j
     on h.isn = j.isn left join
     emilitary em
     on em.emplisn = j.isn and em.milsign = 'Y'
where h.sex = 'М'
group by rollup (d.fullname);
```

Note:  `select distinct` is almost never needed with `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

Most definitly you could do this in a more elegant maner but atleast it works:

```
select d.fullname,count(h.isn) 
from subdept d
left join subhuman h on h.deptisn=d.isn 
left join subject j on h.isn=j.isn 
left join emilitary em on em.emplisn=j.isn 
where h.sex = 'М' and em.milsign='Y' 
group by rollup (d.fullname) 
having count(h.isn)>0
union
select g.fullname, 0 from 
subdept g
where d.fullname not in(
    select tt1.fullname from (
        select d.fullname,count(h.isn) 
        from subdept d 
        left join subhuman h on h.deptisn=d.isn 
        left join subject j on h.isn=j.isn 
        left join emilitary em on em.emplisn=j.isn 
    where h.sex = 'М' and em.milsign='Y' 
    group by rollup (d.fullname) 
    having count(h.isn)>0) tt1
)
```

Comment: sorry I don't have enough reputation((

Answer (score 0):

`where h.sex='m' and and em.milsign='Y'` is causing an "implicit inner join" that will hide some departments if there are no matching rows in the left joined tables. Change both to join conditions instead:

```
SELECT
      d.fullname
    , COUNT(h.isn)
FROM subdept d
LEFT JOIN subhuman h ON d.isn = h.deptisn AND h.sex = 'М'
LEFT JOIN subject j ON h.isn = j.isn
LEFT JOIN emilitary em ON j.isn = em.emplisn AND em.milsign = 'Y'
GROUP BY ROLLUP
      d.fullname
;
```

or, you could modify the where clause to allow NULLs to be retuned by the join conditions:

```
SELECT
      d.fullname
    , COUNT(h.isn)
FROM subdept d
LEFT JOIN subhuman h ON d.isn = h.deptisn
LEFT JOIN subject j ON h.isn = j.isn
LEFT JOIN emilitary em ON j.isn = em.emplisn
WHERE ( h.sex = 'М'  OR h.sex IS NULL)
AND (em.milsign = 'Y' OR em.milsign IS NULL)
GROUP BY ROLLUP
      d.fullname
;
```

Or, apply the wanted filtering within a subquery:

```
SELECT
      d.fullname
    , COUNT(h.isn)
FROM subdept d
LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT
            h.isn
          , h.deptisn
      FROM subhuman h
      LEFT JOIN subject j ON h.isn = j.isn
      LEFT JOIN emilitary em ON j.isn = em.emplisn
      WHERE h.sex = 'М'
      AND em.milsign = 'Y'
) h ON d.isn = h.deptisn
GROUP BY ROLLUP
      d.fullname
;
```